FFmpeg av_read_frame() interrupt_callback
class TimeoutHandler_c
{
public:
  TimeoutHandler_c() = default;
  ~TimeoutHandler_c() = default;
        
  void Reset(time_t timeout_microseconds)
  {
    Timeout = timeout_microseconds;
    TimeLast = GET_US_TIME();
  }
        
  bool IsTimeout()
  {
    const time_t duration = GET_US_TIME() - TimeLast;
    LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "Duration = %lli, timeout = %lli, result %i\n", duration, Timeout, duration > Timeout);
    return duration > Timeout;
  }
        
  static int CheckInterrupt(void* t)
  {
    return t && static_cast<TimeoutHandler_c*>(t)->IsTimeout();
  }
        
  private:
    time_t Timeout{ 0 }; // microseconds
    time_t TimeLast{ 0 }; // microseconds
};
    
...

TimeoutHandler_c TimeoutHandler; //!< Control maximum time of packets waiting
AvFormatContext->interrupt_callback.opaque = (void*)&TimeoutHandler;
AvFormatContext->interrupt_callback.callback = &TimeoutHandler_c::CheckInterrupt;
    
...

while(1)
{
  ...
  TimeoutHandler.Reset(10000000);
  time_t time_before_av_read_frame = GET_US_TIME(); // microseconds
  int av_res = av_read_frame(AvFormatContext, av_packet.get());
  time_t time_after_av_read_frame = GET_US_TIME(); // microseconds
  LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "av_read_frame() res %i, time %lli, time_limit %lli\n", av_res, time_after_av_read_frame - time_before_av_read_frame, options_open->ReadFrameTimeout);
    
  if (av_res == 0) // packet with frame
  {
    LOG(LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "AVPacket(%i): stream_index %i, pts %lli, dts %lli, time_base.num %i, time_base.den %i, duration %lli, size %i, flags 0x%x, pos %lli, side_data_elems %i\n", av_packet_cnt, av_packet->stream_index, av_packet->pts, av_packet->dts, av_packet->time_base.num, av_packet->time_base.den, av_packet->duration, av_packet->size, av_packet->flags, av_packet->pos, av_packet->side_data_elems);
    ++av_packet_cnt;
    av_read_frame_error_count = 0;
  }
  else // no packet
  {
    ++av_read_frame_error_count;
    LOG(LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, "No av_packet, %lli errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: %s\n", av_read_frame_error_count, av_err2str(av_res));
  }
  ...
}

Logging (times in microseconds):
10:52:50.234176:Run(925): av_read_frame() res 0, time 20354, time_limit 10000000
10:52:50.234235:Run(931): AVPacket(1695): stream_index 1, pts 661875112, dts 661875112, time_base.num 0, time_base.den 1, duration 1920, size 251, flags 0x1, pos 6341240, side_data_elems 1
10:52:50.234272:Run(925): av_read_frame() res 0, time 1, time_limit 10000000
10:52:50.234293:Run(931): AVPacket(1696): stream_index 1, pts 661877032, dts 661877032, time_base.num 0, time_base.den 1, duration 1920, size 250, flags 0x1, pos -1, side_data_elems 0
10:52:50.234319:Run(925): av_read_frame() res 0, time 1, time_limit 10000000
10:52:50.234338:Run(931): AVPacket(1697): stream_index 1, pts 661878952, dts 661878952, time_base.num 0, time_base.den 1, duration 1920, size 287, flags 0x1, pos -1, side_data_elems 0
10:52:50.234365:Run(925): av_read_frame() res 0, time 0, time_limit 10000000
10:52:50.234393:Run(931): AVPacket(1698): stream_index 1, pts 661880872, dts 661880872, time_base.num 0, time_base.den 1, duration 1920, size 323, flags 0x1, pos -1, side_data_elems 0
10:52:50.234423:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:50.345009:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 110579, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:50.456198:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 221772, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:50.566359:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 331934, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:50.675843:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 441409, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:50.785050:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 550621, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:50.906415:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 671985, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.030219:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 795790, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.155401:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 920970, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.280220:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1045789, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.405379:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1170948, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.530548:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1296118, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.655525:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1421099, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.780054:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1545622, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:51.905742:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1671312, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.030028:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1795598, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.156941:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 1922516, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.280096:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2045669, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.405634:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2171209, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.530967:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2296541, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.655179:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2420754, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.781832:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2547403, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:52.905314:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2670889, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.030055:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2795630, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.155874:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 2921448, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.281438:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3047014, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.405043:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3170613, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.531218:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3296793, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.656935:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3422504, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.781820:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3547395, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:53.907028:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3672600, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.030327:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3795899, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.155265:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 3920833, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.281383:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4046958, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.405035:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4170604, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.530395:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4295971, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.655403:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4420976, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.780385:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4545954, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:54.905529:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4671098, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.030476:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4796050, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.155904:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 4921479, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.280770:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5046339, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.405693:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5171254, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.530824:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5296397, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.655984:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5421559, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.780807:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5546382, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:55.905002:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5670577, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.030066:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5795641, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.155151:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 5920726, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.281405:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6046980, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.406788:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6172357, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.530478:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6296054, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.656392:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6421968, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.781922:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6547497, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:56.905743:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6671311, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.031014:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6796589, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.155710:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 6921282, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.281593:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7047168, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.406115:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7171690, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.530220:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7295796, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.655566:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7421135, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.780723:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7546298, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:57.905480:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7671050, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.030799:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7796375, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.155789:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 7921364, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.281769:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8047344, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.405858:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8171427, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.531698:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8297271, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.656105:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8421681, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.780503:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8546072, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:58.905195:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8670770, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.030539:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8796114, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.156909:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 8922482, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.281819:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9047392, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.405967:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9171536, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.531362:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9296937, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.655612:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9421181, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.780532:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9546101, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:52:59.906761:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9672331, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:53:00.030563:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9796138, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:53:00.156556:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 9922131, timeout = 10000000, result 0
10:53:00.280257:IsTimeout(146): Duration = 10045828, timeout = 10000000, result 1
10:53:00.280398:Run(925): av_read_frame() res 0, time 10045975, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.280420:Run(931): AVPacket(1699): stream_index 0, pts 661881817, dts 661874257, time_base.num 0, time_base.den 1, duration 3753, size 1874, flags 0x0, pos 6334472, side_data_elems 1
10:53:00.280480:Run(925): av_read_frame() res 0, time 21, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.280501:Run(931): AVPacket(1700): stream_index 0, pts 661878037, dts 661878037, time_base.num 0, time_base.den 1, duration 3753, size 1154, flags 0x0, pos 6339924, side_data_elems 0
10:53:00.280533:Run(925): av_read_frame() res -1414092869, time 5, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.280561:Run(952): No av_packet, 1 errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: Immediate exit requested
10:53:00.290830:Run(925): av_read_frame() res -1414092869, time 17, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.290862:Run(952): No av_packet, 2 errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: Immediate exit requested
10:53:00.301673:Run(925): av_read_frame() res -1414092869, time 25, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.301725:Run(952): No av_packet, 3 errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: Immediate exit requested
10:53:00.312259:Run(925): av_read_frame() res -1414092869, time 10, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.312308:Run(952): No av_packet, 4 errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: Immediate exit requested
10:53:00.323144:Run(925): av_read_frame() res -1414092869, time 11, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.323196:Run(952): No av_packet, 5 errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: Immediate exit requested
10:53:00.334049:Run(925): av_read_frame() res -1414092869, time 9, time_limit 10000000
10:53:00.334101:Run(952): No av_packet, 6 errors in a row. av_read_frame() failed with averror: Immediate exit requested

I start broadcasting to the address udp://239.0.0.1:6688. I start receiving data successfully. Then I stop broadcasting. As a result, the av_read_frame(), as expected, is blocked for 10 seconds, which I set before calling av_read_frame().
But I have two questions:

Why, after 10 seconds of blocking and exiting at the maximum waiting time I set, I get 2 good video frames (stream_index 0). Why don't I get these frames earlier? It seems that the blocking occurs while waiting for elementary audio stream data (stream_index 1), although the elementary video stream data (stream_index 0) is available. But this can't be true, can it?
Why do I get "Immediate exit requested" errors with a frequency of 10 milliseconds, although I set the maximum waiting time to 10 seconds each time before av_read_frame()? Or is the "Immediate exit requested" error not related to the maximum wait time I set? How is this situation different from waiting for data for 10 seconds earlier, when the broadcast was also already stopped? I saw that ffplay in some situations uses a wait of 10 milliseconds (https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffplay_8c_source.html#l03023)

